# Correct way to select the Selector

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

In my TestCafe script I try to select 3 inputs. They are:

```html
<div>
<div class="InputHeaderContainer cl-input-header-container">
<div class="cl-input-header-text">Korpushöhe (ohne Sockel)</div>
<input class="InputField cl-input cl-input-header" type="number" value="600">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="InputHeaderContainer cl-input-header-container">
<div class="cl-input-header-text">Korpusbreite</div>
<input class="InputField cl-input cl-input-header" type="number" value="600">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="InputHeaderContainer cl-input-header-container">
<div class="cl-input-header-text">Korpusbreite</div>
<input class="InputField cl-input cl-input-header" type="number" value="600">
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used in my script:

```js
await t
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpushöhe').find('input'), '1200', {replace: true})
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpusbreite').find('input'), '1400', {replace: true})
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpustiefe').find('input'), '400', {replace: true});
```

But if I run this script, the Browser will type the text 3 times into the first field. This is confusing. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Give a try by using 'sibling'.

[Refer documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#sibling)

```
await t
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpushöhe').sibling('input'), '1200', {replace: true})
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpusbreite').sibling('input'), '1400', {replace: true})
    .typeText(Selector('div').withText('Korpustiefe').sibling('input'), '400', {replace: true})
```